# timing the execution of a source command

Tags: command-line, performance, zsh, source

I'm trying to improve the execution of my zsh dotfiles, and I need to time the execution my sub-scripts.  I have a section of code in my `.zshrc` looking like this:

```
typeset -U config_files
config_files=($DOTFILES/**/*.zsh)
for file in  ${(M)config_files}
do
    source file
done
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
for file in  ${(M)config_files}
do
    \time -f %E source file
done
```

But unfortunately, I get this kind of response:

```
time: cannot run source: No such file or directory
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is a builtin, not an external command, so using the external `time` to time it doesn't make sense. Do either of:

```sh
TIMEFMT=%E
for file in  ${(M)config_files}
do
    time (source file)
done
```

Or:

```sh
for file in  ${(M)config_files}
do
    \time -f %E zsh -c 'source "$1"' zsh "$file"
done
```

In the former, [the subshell is necessary because](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00066.html):

> Additional note:  The time builtin applied to any construct that is
>   executed in the current shell, is silently ignored.  So although it's
>   syntactically OK to put an opening curly or a repeat-loop or the like
>   immediately after the time keyword, you'll get no timing statistics. 
>   You have to use parens instead, to force a subshell, which is then
>   timed.

And in the latter case, you're starting a new zsh instance for each file. So, in both cases, there's no way for easily timing dependent scripts (i.e., where one config file does something that is required by or somehow affects another config file). Alternately, you can save the output of `time` after each source, which will give you cumulative timing:

```sh
TIMEFMT=%E
{time} 2> times
for file in  ${(M)config_files}
do
    source file
    {time} 2>> times
done
```

Then you can use `awk` or something to get the individual timings:

```sh
awk 'NR != 1 {print $0 - prev} {prev = $0; getline}' times
```

Comment: thanks @muru.  These can certainly help in my quest to improve my startup times, so thanks for that.  I won't be able to leave the sub-shell option in place, since I'm defining aliases and functions. But the first option works by the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the `man time` command and noted

```
Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run
the external time command and not the shell builtin variant.  On system
where time is installed in /usr/bin, the first example would become
```

so I'm guessing you should provide a path for time.
Please note i have no experience in zsh